# How to communicate between Fragment and an non-hosting Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface, callback

I have an Activity A that is a Main Activity with navigation menu and toolbar that is hosting a Viewpager with fragments. Lets say Fragment B in that viewpager starts intent with Activity C with a button clicked.

Activity C is a Video Player activity which need to trigger a method in Fragment B by using a callback and then Fragment B calls a method in Activity C.

I know Fragment and Activity can communicate using Interfaces, but as you probably understood, Activity C is not hosting Fragment B.

So is it possible to do this kind of interface between the two? Do I need to change my overall design ?

Comment: You can go from that particular Fragment to own host activity ,then go from there to desire ativity

Answer (score 0):

> So is it possible to do this kind of interface between the two?

It depends on what exactly you are doing, but as you wrote it, I would give it a solid "no."

In your scenario, Fragment B is not visible when Activity C is displayed. Fragment B will be stopped (i.e. `onStop()` has been called), and thus you really shouldn't be doing anything with it.

It sounds like you need a slightly different architecture in which the component that needs to be shared between Fragment B and Activity C exists as a separate component that lives independently of Fragment B and Activity C's lifecycles.

Comment: Any suggested approach? If Activity C would be Fragment added on top of Fragment B, will it work somehow? I'm seriously stuck on this issue for a while now.